# file inbound-channel-adapter performance issue

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-rabbit

We have a spring integration application which will monitor on an incoming folder then process the files. 
When the application is down for maintenance or some other reason the incoming folder is filled with 100K files by upstream application.
When restart application it is getting frozen it is not processing incoming files may be trying to load all the incoming files.

Here is configuration

```
<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="inFiles" channel="inFilesin" directory="file:${incoming.folder}" 
    queue-size="300" filename-regex="(?i)^(?!.*writing) " auto-startup="true" auto-create-directory="false" >
        <int:poller id="fw.fileInboudPoller" fixed-rate="1" receive-timeout="3" time-unit="SECONDS"
            max-messages-per-poll="10" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="10-20" queue-capacity="20" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" />
```

Appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Mohan

Answer (score 0):

Suggest change `fixed-rate` to `fixed-delay`.

Your files are processed very slow and the first option sais that the new task should be started just afer that time (in your case 1 sec.).

Another problem - `rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"`. In this casem if your thead queue will be exhausted (and it is in you case of 100K files), the scheduled thread does the real work.
Poller, to schedule tasks, uses `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` with size **10**. So, with this "havy-load" your app may be frozen, because that **pool** is shared for all application.

So, try to use `fixed-delay`. In this case your app won't be frozen, but files will be processed slower.

Maybe this can help you: [`<int:resource-inbound-channel-adapter>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/resource.html) ?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I changed to fixed-delay but not  fixed the issue.

Thanks,
Madan

Comment: Gary : Any suggestion?

Comment: It seems I have to set prevent-duplicates="false" to take queue-size="300" value effective.