# file inbound adapter Multiple threads processing same file

Tags: spring, integration, spring-integration, spring-rabbit

We have a spring integration application which will monitor on an incoming folder then process the files. I was using prevent-duplicates="true" but I have to change to false. 
Here I explained the reason.
[file inbound-channel-adapter performance issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054190/file-inbound-channel-adapter-performance-issue)

Now I am seeing multiple threads processing same file. I appreciate help!

```
<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="inFiles" channel="inFilesin" directory="file:${incoming.folder}" 
    queue-size="300" filename-regex="(?i)^(?!.*writing)" prevent-duplicates="false" auto-startup="true" auto-create-directory="false" >
        <int:poller id="fw.fileInboudPoller" fixed-rate="1" receive-timeout="3" time-unit="SECONDS"
            max-messages-per-poll="10" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="10-20" queue-capacity="20" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" />
```

Thanks, 
Mohan

Answer (score 0):

As you have found, there are difficulties scaling, when a filesystem has a very large number of files.

You might want to consider alternative technologies, Rabbit, JMS, etc.

Alternatively, you can implement a custom file locker or directory scanner as [described here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/3.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/files.html#file-reading).

The provided nio-locker won't help because it doesn't prevent multi-threaded access in this case.

Comment: Gary, Thanks for your help. We are using Rabbit, This module is doing move the file from one folder to another folder then create a record into DB and a message to Rabbit.

Comment: Right, but my point is from your other question "When the application is down for maintenance or some other reason the incoming folder is filled with 100K files by upstream application." It would be better to have the upstream application use Rabbit instead of the filesystem. If you can't afford to include the data from the file in rabbit messages, then at least send a notification of a file's presence using Rabbit, rather than scanning tens of thousands of files on the file system.

Comment: That is good point but the Upstream application collects the files from different sources and that application does not have access to Rabbit and DB for security reasons.

Comment: So a custom scanner or locker is probably your only choice.

Comment: Gary,  We are still seeing multiple threads are trying to process same file that causing second thread throwing java.io.FileNotFoundException.  I see new API support in Spring 4 ConcurrentMetadataStore / RedisMetadataStore.  Can that prevent multiple threads processing same file on same JVM or different JVM? If Yes can you point me to sample example or configuration.-- Mohan

Comment: See [the documentation about FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/files.html#file-reading).